# Commutative diagram with curved arrow

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I want to get a bent arrow from node A to node E, this is my code:

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (E) at (0,0) {$T_V U$};
\node[right=of E] (F) {$U\times V$};
\node[below=of F] (A) {$U$};
\node [right=of F] (D) {};
\node [below=of D] (G) {$V$};


\draw[->] (E)--(F) node [midway,above] {$\simeq$};
\draw[->] (E)--(A) node [midway,below] {$f$};
\draw[->] (F)--(A) node [midway,right] {$\pi^2$};
\draw[->] (F)--(G) node [midway,right] {$\pi^1$};
\draw[->,bend] (A)--(E) node [midway,left] {$v$}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `tikz-cd` directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
T_V U \arrow [dr,"f"] \arrow[r,"\simeq"] &
  U\times V \arrow[d,"\pi^2"] \arrow[dr,"\pi^1"] \\
& U \arrow[ul,bend left,"v"] & V
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was simple and nice

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of it, here is what went wrong with `tikz` version.

When you want to bend, you have to say `bend left` or `bend right`. and this operation needs either `to` or `edge` path, not `--`. The last point is that you have to use proper placements for nodes like `abobe`, `above right` etc as appropriate. When you use `node` soon after `to`, the default position will be `midway` hence you don't need to specify it. Altogether, this works:

```
\draw[->,bend left] (A) to node [left] {$v$} (E) ;
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (E) at (0,0) {$T_V U$};
\node[right=of E] (F) {$U\times V$};
\node[below=of F] (A) {$U$};
\node [right=of F] (D) {};
\node [below=of D] (G) {$V$};


\draw[->] (E)--(F) node [midway,above] {$\simeq$};
\draw[->] (E)--(A) node [midway,above] {$f$};
\draw[->] (F)--(A) node [midway,right] {$\pi^2$};
\draw[->] (F)--(G) node [midway,above right] {$\pi^1$};
\draw[->,bend left] (A) to node [left] {$v$} (E) ;


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But for commutative diagrams, use `tikz-cd` and live happier.